# Retrieve POST data in the order they were sent in in Django

Tags: django, paypal, http-post

Is there a way to get data POSTed to a Django view in the order in which it appeared in the HTTP header?

The reason I need this is for PayPal's Instant Payment Notification - you have to acknowledge the notification by sending the data back in exactly the same order to ensure the integrity of the data. I can't figure this one out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe [HttpRequest.raw_post_data](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.raw_post_data) can be your friend? It is available since Django 1.3.

Comment: Renamed to `HttpRequest.body` in recent versions