# Django request.POST dictionary order from the client side to the server side

Tags: python, django

Can someone point me in the right direction. Essentially, I have a `<form>` that has a variable number of fields:

```
<input value="1" name="cat">
<input value="2" name="dog">
<input value="3" name="tiger">
```

When I look at the `request.POST`, the dictionary order is off:

```
{'dog':['2'], 'cat':[1], 'tiger':['3']}
```

I realize that dictionary ordering is not maintained within Python - however I need a way to get that ordering back on the backend.

How could I go about doing this? My first idea is using JS, but I was hoping there would be a better way.

Comment: use collections.OrderedDict([items]) find out more [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: it depends of what you need after but you can convert you dict in list of tuples like that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value

Comment: I think the POST request comes in unordered though. Django converts the HTTP request to a dictionary. I would need to hijack that process to use the above method - right?

Comment: I'm trying to think of a reason why you would need to rely on the order of fields. Why not use some explicit naming convention instead?

Comment: So the fields are 'sortable' - the mod removed that little tidbit. I need to hold the order because I want to be able to create and save custom forms via sorting them on the frontend.

Comment: @SomeDeveloper you should submit the sort order as separate field(s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who are asking why you'd need to rely on the order of the fields - there are cases. In my case, I was accepting a PayPal IPN, which required the data to be hashed in a correct order for the response.

Anyway, this was my original question: [Retrieve POST data in the order they were sent in in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451335/retrieve-post-data-in-the-order-they-were-sent-in-in-django)

You can basically use [HttpRequest.body](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body) (this was called `raw_post_data` in 1.4 and below). However - remember that it is up to the browser to send the data, and I don't know whether browsers guarantee order of the form fields when you submit the form.

Comment: I saw that in the docs so I'm playing around with it right now. Thanks!